# Python: Detect if certain variable is inputted into function argument

Tags: python

How can I make a `function` recognize if a certain `variable` is inputted as an argument?

I would like to input a number of variables into the function, and if they are present, return corresponding binary variables as `True` to the program.

```
#variables to test: x, y, z

def switch(*variables):
    for var in list(variables):
        #detect if var is the variable x:
            switch_x = True
        #detect if var is the variable y:
            switch_y = True
        #detect if var is the variable z:
            switch_z = True

switch(x, y, z)

if switch_x is True:
    #Do something
```

Note that I'm looking to test if the *variables* themselves are inputted into the function. Not the *values* that the variables contain.

Comment: You get passed in the *values*, not the original variables. So no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible to do with `*args`, but you can use [`**kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python) to achieve similar behaviour. You define your function as:

```
def switch(**variables):
    if 'x' in variables:
        switch_x = True
    if 'y' in variables:
        switch_y = True
    if 'z' in variables:
        switch_z = True
```

And call like:

```
switch(x=5, y=4)
switch(x=5)
# or
switch(z=5)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But this is looking for parts of strings, is it not? The variables I use are set to `False` from the start, and are then supposed to switch to `True` if they are inputted into the function. Although perhaps a workaround is to set the variables to contain their name as a string? As so: `x = 'x';` ... if `'x' in variables:`

Comment: No, it's not. Read linked question  about `**kwargs` carefully. When you call `switch(x=5, y=4)`, your `variables` will become a `dict` with two items, like `{'x': 5, 'y': 4}`. And `in` operator checks if the item with particular name is present in this `dict` (effectively checking whether *any* value was passed in using `x=ANY_VALUE`).

Comment: From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict): `key in d` Return True if `d` has a key `key`, else False. Sorry if my wording was a bit misleading.